# Use Stored Procedure with Entity Framework to select child objects in parent entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net

If I'm using Entity Framework and I have a parent table with a one to many relationship with a child table, and I want to use a stored procedure to return the parent's children, would I add a new property to my parent model (like GetChildren) and use the function import and then call that property instead of the default ‘child’ entity to use my stored procedure?

Is this possible, and if so, any good links to any tutorials?  Not sure what I should search on and how this would be done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't want to use a navigation **property** but a loading **method**.

If yes, imho, such a method should be at DAL or repository level not at business level. So, as a pseudo implementation, your implementation should look like this:

```
public class MasterBC {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    //...
}

public class ChildBC {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    //...
}

public class DALContext : DbContext() {
    IDbSet<MasterBC> Masters {get; set;}

    IEnumerable<ChildBC> GetChildren(Int32 id) {
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<ChildBC>("exec usp_name {0}", id);
    }
}
```

But, why not use a navigation property ?

Comment: can I map a stored procedure to a navigation property?